# Error: "The node to be inserted is from a different document context"

Tags: c#, xml

When I am calling `XmlNode.AppendChild()`, I get this error:

> The node to be inserted is from a different document context.

```
static public XmlNode XMLNewChildNode(XmlNode oParent, string sName, 
    string sNamespaceURI, string sNodeType)
{
    XmlNode oNode = moDoc.CreateNode(sNodeType, sName, sNamespaceURI);
    oParent.AppendChild(oNode);
    return oNode;
}
```

This code was converted from its VB 6.0 version which was this (please ignore the optional parameters, I have overloads for them in C# version):

```
Public Function XMLNewChildNode(ByVal oParent As IXMLDOMNode, ByVal _
    sName As String, Optional ByVal sNamespaceURI As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal sNodeType As String = "element") As IXMLDOMNode
'**************** DESCRIPTION *******************
  'Create a new Child Node for passed Parent.
'***************** VARIABLES ********************
  Dim oNode As IXMLDOMNode
'************************************************
  Set oNode = moDoc.createNode(sNodeType, sName, sNamespaceURI)
  Call oParent.appendChild(oNode)
  Set XMLNewChildNode = oNode
End Function
```

Why does the VB code work while the C# does not? Are there differences between how VB and C# handle XML, that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

You need to import the node into the document before appending it:

```
XmlNode oNode = moDoc.CreateNode(sNodeType, sName, sNamespaceURI);

//necessary for crossing XmlDocument contexts
XmlNode importNode = oParent.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(oNode, true);

oParent.AppendChild(importNode);
return oNode;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! ImportNode takes two params... the second one is for deepClone ... How can I decide if I should pass True or False to it?

Comment: @BDotA true if you want to import the node and all its children; false if you just want to import the top-level node.

Comment: thanks ... I tried both true and false and I am getting Null Ref Exception on the ImportNode line... is it still something with my XML codes? or this one is related to the data that I am passing ?

Comment: @BDotA debug and figure out which object is null

Comment: if `OwnerDoccument` is null; `ImportNode(..` should be called on `oParent`?

Comment: ...yes, `oParent.ImportNode(oNode, true);`

Comment: the OwnerDocument was not necessary for me. Just oParent.ImportNode(oNode, true); was enough

Comment: Didn't work for me. OwnerDocument was null, and even calling ImportNode on the document still failed too.

Comment: OwnerDocument is always null for me, too, and trying to add a 2nd node gives me the error "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."