# Better way to convert a string to XmlNode in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I wanted to convert a string (which obviously is an xml) to an XmlNode in C#.While searching the net I got this code.I would like to know whether this is a good way to convert a string to XmlNode?  I have to preform this conversion within a loop, so does it cause any performace issues?

```
        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlContent));
        XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode newNode = myXmlDocument.ReadNode(textReader);
```

Please reply,

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 119, accepted):

should be straight-forward:

```
        string xmlContent = "<foo></foo>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlContent);
        XmlNode newNode = doc.DocumentElement;
```

or with LINQ if that's an option:

```
        XElement newNode  = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent).Root;
```

Comment: I get this error when I try this: `The node to be inserted is from a different document context.`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019136/the-node-to-be-inserted-is-from-a-different-document-context

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I tried the LINQ option first that cause but problems.  Because I the calling method couldn't handle System.Xml.Linq.XmlElement.

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440649/unable-to-get-values-from-soap-response-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works only for single element. XmlNode can have multiple elements like `string xmlContent = "<foo></foo><bar></bar>";` (Exception: "There are multiple root elements");

To load multiple elements use this:

```c#
string xmlContent = "<foo></foo><bar></bar>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<singleroot>"+xmlContent+"</singleroot>");
XmlNode newNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/singleroot");
```

Answer (score -4):

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.