# How do I set a xml Node to contain a string's content?

Tags: c#, xml, string

Let's say I have one string called `data`.
How do i put a string's text inside one of it's nodes? How do i choose which one contains the string? 
unlike the other questions i saw, my xml will contain many tags. so i dont want so set it to contain one thing, but to add it to the others.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/4130358/3434672

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to convert a string to XmlNode in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130341/better-way-to-convert-a-string-to-xmlnode-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to add a text node to your XML file with the `data` you have:

```
// Open the XML
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<somedata><moredata>sometext</moredata></somedata>");
// Create the new node, set to text and insert the data
XmlNode newElem = doc.CreateNode("text", "yournodename", "");
newElem.InnerText = data;   
// Write the new node and append
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
root.AppendChild(newElem);
```

If you need something more specific, please provide some more information regarding the node name or the XML Document etc.

**UPDATE:** As mentioned in the comments, the above code will modify but not save the modifications to the XML. To do so, load the XML document using `doc.Load("pathtoyourxml.xml")` instead of using `doc.LoadXml()` and save it to the same path using `doc.Save("pathtoyourxml.xml")` after doing whatever you are doing with it.

Comment: i thought this should work. but it didnt; `XmlDocument data = new XmlDocument();
            data.Load(code_file);
            Console.WriteLine(data.ChildNodes[1].InnerXml);
            username = data.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(code_file); `

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work. i mean i did it, i told the program to show whats inside `newElem`, it di show the text i wanted it to show, but after i closed and reopend, the xml was empty, and the program didn show a thing

Comment: @JonathanMoreno answer has been updated with proper save/load for the XML file.

Comment: sorry i was not here. just came home from a vacation. Well, i tried what you said about changing the `LoadXml` to `Load` , and i got this error. im sure the path is right and im not so sure whats wrong; https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHXXml);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true @chalarangelo