# Powershell - how to add <sectionGroup> to web.config

Tags: powershell, web-config, configsection

I'm trying to add a `sectionGroup` element to the `configuration/configSections` element in a web.config using Powershell.

I currently have

```
$filePath = [path to my web.config file]

# load the XML from the web.config
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)

# navigate to the <configSections> element
$xmlConfigSections = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/configSections")

# create the new <sectionGroup> element with a 'name' attribute
$sectionGroup = $xml.CreateElement("sectionGroup")
$xmlAttr = $xml.CreateAttribute("name")
$xmlAttr.Value = "myCustomSectionGroup"
$sectionGroup.Attributes.Append($xmlAttr)

# now add the new <sectionGroup> element to the <configSections> element
$xmlConfigSections.AppendChild($sectionGroup)

#save the web.config
$xml.Save($filePath)
```

But this incurs an exception on the `CreateElement` method:

> "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this
>   node, because the specified node is the wrong type."

I don't understand why such an exception is being thrown when I try to *create* the element (the exception appears to relate to appending an element).

Something else I've tried is

```
$newConfig = [xml]@'<sectionGroup name="myCustomSectionGroup"></sectionGroup>'@

$filePath = [path to my web.config file]

# load the XML from the web.config
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)

# navigate to the <configSections> element
$xmlConfigSections = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/configSections")

$xmlConfigSections.AppendChild($newConfig)
```

But this throws the exact same exception as previously.

`<sectionGroup>` is definitely a valid child of `<configSections>`.

Ideally, I'd prefer if the second attempt worked because this doesn't require me to declare every element, every attribute, *etc*.

Can someone please explain to me why the `<configSections>` node isn't allowing my `<sectionGroup>` element?

Comment: Full stack trace will help a lot. Currently your code is completely fine. It runs in command line it runs in PowerGui. `CreateElement` is unlikely to produce the exception you are describing. I think there is something that you are doing that you are not telling us. Thus, please get the stack trace by reading `$error[0].Exception.InnerException.StackTrace` right after the exception you are discribing happens.

Comment: If I use the script from my second example, then request the StackTrace, the exception is "at System.Xml.XmlNode.AppendChild(XmlNode newChild
   at AppendChild(Object , Object[] )
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.Auxi
tion methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments)"

Comment: I would still prefer to use the version above which has the XML (to be inserted) as an XML document which is then appended, rather than writing it all out element for element, attribute by attribute (as in the answer below). Having the XML declared as a variable seems more maintainable and readable, so I'd appreciate if you can point out what you think might be the problem with this method.

Comment: Yes, the stack trace indicates that it's not the `CreateElement` which is failing, but `AppendChild`. The `DotNetAdapter` line indicates that you are calling this dot net method from powershell code. (Which you indeed do) Try dumping the method arguments before you call `AppendChild` they must have something that we are not expecting. Some node types can't be added to other node types, and (like can't add element to an attribute) and incompatibility like this is what ultimately causing your exception.

Comment: You want to dump the `NodeType` property both on the object you are calling `AppendChild` that produces the error on and the object that you are passing to `AppendChild`.

Comment: The object that I'm trying to append shows up as a Document, whereas it probably expects an Element. So I wrapped the declared XML in a <root> element and then called AppendChild($newConfig.SelectSingleNode("/root")). The exception then thrown is "The node to be 
inserted is from a different document context." So is it even possible to insert a pre-declared XML element?

Comment: This way perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3019218/284111

Comment: It's now throwing null reference exceptions, but I really appreciate your help, @zespri, and realise that I'm probably now outwith the scope of my OP, so I'll carry on investigating but atleast I know that I can use the slightly more obtuse method in the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$filePath = [path to my web.config file]

# load the XML from the web.config
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)

$sectionGroup = $xml.CreateElement('sectionGroup')
$sectionGroup.SetAttribute('name','myCustomSectionGroup')
$sectionGroupChild = $xml.CreateElement('sectionGroupChild')
$sectionGroupChild.SetAttribute('name','myCustomSectionGroup')

$newNode = $xml.configuration.configSections.AppendChild($sectionGroup)
$newNode.AppendChild($sectionGroupChild)

$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. On the "CreateElement" call it throws the exception "The specified node cannot be 
inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."

Comment: That's a shame, and odd, the code in my answer works perfectly for me and I can't get it to throw any exceptions.

Comment: I wonder if it might be related to the environment? I'm building a script for a NuGet package, but am currently testing it in PowerGUI with a hardcoded filepath. I've temporarily changed the ExecutionPolicy on my machine to 'Unrestricted' and the web.config file is not open anywhere else (though its parent project is open in VS).
Does anything there sound a possible cause of the problem?

Comment: Possibly, but the way to rule it out is run it from the powershell command line.

Comment: I've now got it working by saving it as a .ps1 file and running that - it still throws an exception in PowerGUI. So now that I have it running (as a file) I'd like to add child nodes inside `myCustomSectionGroup`, but when I call `CreateElement` a second time it throws that same exception.
Am I right to be calling `$xml.CreateElement("section")` a second time, or should it then be `$sectionGroup.CreateElement("section")`? [Both throw exceptions.] 
Also, I don't need to save the file, or append `myCustomGroup` immediately after creating it, do I? I can add everything, then append and save?

Comment: I've updated my example with the child node, the CreateElement returns a reference to the new node for which you can add a new element.  You can leave the saving until the end.

Comment: Ok, I think (and hope) that I can take it from here, now that I see how to append attributes and inner elements. Sincere thanks for your help, David.