# How to set XmlNode to Clipboard?

Tags: c#

Im trying to set an `XMLNode` to the Clipboard using the `SetData` command. I get the `OutOfMemoryException`.

How can I make the `XMLNode` Class serializable, or do I need to serialize every Node manually and then deserialize in the Paste function?

Copy function:

```
Clipboard.SetData("XmlNode", ouritem);
```

Paste function:

```
XmlNode ournode = Clipboard.GetData("XmlNode") as XmlNode;
```

Comment: What heve you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Of course, I will update the post.

Comment: It could be that the `XmlNode` object's circular references (e.g. from the node to its parent and back) are causing the OutOfMemoryException. What if you just put `ouritem.OuterXml` (which is a `string`) in the clipboard?

Comment: That seems to do the trick, how can I cast back to an XMlNode when I have the OuterXml pasted as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the `XmlNode` object's circular references (e.g. from the node to its parent and back) and references to all sorts of other data are causing the OutOfMemoryException.

You can place the node's XML on the clipboard as a string, and then reconstitute it later:

```
Clipboard.SetData("XmlNode", ouritem.OuterXml);
```

Paste function:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(Clipboard.GetData("XmlNode") as string);
XmlNode ournode = doc.DocumentElement;
```

Of course, one consequence of this is that this would result in an isolated node without the associations to everything else in the document that contained it.

Comment: Thanks, I used your answer and the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019136/the-node-to-be-inserted-is-from-a-different-document-context to complete my question