# Appending an XML Document with elements from another XML Document in C#

Tags: c#, xml, forms, visual-studio

I am trying to build an automatic test grading application and I want the end result to be a savefiledialog prompt that allows the grader to save a new xml file to any location.

The trick is I need that output xml to include the original test + appended answers from  answer key + final grade.  Here is what I have so far but Im getting an error.  I am not familiar with .appendchild() so Im thinking that is where my issue lies.

```
    private void cbOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlNode rootTest = xmlAnswers.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode rootKey = xmlAnswerKey.DocumentElement;

        XmlNodeList nodeListTest = rootTest.SelectNodes("//answer");

        foreach (XmlNode item in nodeListTest)
        {
            XmlNode importNode = rootTest.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(rootKey, true);

            item.AppendChild(importNode);
        }

        SaveFileDialog savefiledialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files|*.XML";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Choose Location to Save Graded Test";

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(savefiledialog1.FileName))
            using (Stream s = File.Open(savefiledialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
            {
                sw.Write(rootTest + tbTotal.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "The node to be inserted is from a different document context"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019136/error-the-node-to-be-inserted-is-from-a-different-document-context)

Comment: This worked for getting past that error.  Now when I run and go through the test I get no output, meaning the file doesnt save anywhere.  I have updated my code above

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time following your code, since it is pre `.Net 3.5` XML code. I started in on C# when 3.5 came out. Seems like you are adding the keys to every answer in the test? Doesn't make sense from what you wrote as your description. But if that was your goal, you can try this.

If you can use .Net 3.5 then use `XElement` / `XDocument`, using [these converters](https://gist.github.com/ChuckSavage/4991478) do

```
XElement test = xmlAnswers.ToXElement();
XElement keys = xmlAnswerKey.ToXElement();

test.Descendants("answer")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(a => a.Add(new XElement(keys))); // Add clone of keys to each answer
// Dialog stuff
test.Save(savefiledialog1.FileName);
```

Or, using your description (I'll have to try and make up what you should be doing, since your XML is hidden from us).

```
XElement test = xmlAnswers.ToXElement();
XElement keys = xmlAnswerKey.ToXElement();

test.Add(keys.Descendants("answer").ToList()); // Add Answers to test
test.Add(new XElement("finalgrade", "A")); // Add final grade
// Dialog stuff
test.Save(savefiledialog1.FileName);
```

PS, don't do all the converting, adding of answers etc outside the

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

Otherwise, if it isn't `OK` then you are wasting the time of your user.

Comment: Thank you Chuck.  I am trying extract the answers from the answer key and append them to the test xml essentially.  This is my answer key: <TestKey>
 <Questions>
   <Q1>
   <weight>15%</weight>
         <answer>A</answer>
     </Q1>
</TestKey>

Comment: @BrandonMR Then the 2nd part I wrote may work for you, if your `TestKey` is in the `xmlAnswerKey` variable of yours. If not, you may want to adjust your post with example XML for both files, so that we can assist you better.

Comment: @BrandonMR Also add an example of what the final XML should look like.