# Merging XML Documents to add Message to Soap Envelope - System.ArgumentException: The node to be inserted is from a different document context

Tags: c#, xml, soap, appendchild

We are using an API that can have multiple messages and other configurations as a child of the transaction tag.

```
public XmlDocument SoapRequestEnvelope()
{
    XmlDocument envelope = new XmlDocument();
    envelope.LoadXml(@"
        <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:tyl=""http://www.VendorWeb.com"" xmlns:wsa=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"" xmlns:wsu=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">
            <soap:Header>
                <wsa:To>https://test.VendorAccess.cloud/ExternalWebService/TranslationBridgeExternalService.asmx</wsa:To>
                <wsa:Action>http://www.MyVendor.com/VendorApiTxnExecutionSyncXml</wsa:Action>
                <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand=""1"">
                    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id =""Timestamp -Redacted"">
                    <wsu:Created>2018-01-10T00:00:00Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2023-03-31T23:59:59Z</wsu:Expires>
                    </wsu:Timestamp>
                    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=""SecurityToken-Redacted"">
                    <wsse:Username>UserName</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
                    </wsse:UsernameToken>
                </wsse:Security>
                <tyl:ApiMessageContext>
                    <tyl:SystemEnvironment>MySiteTest</tyl:SystemEnvironment>
                    <tyl:RetryCount> 0 </tyl:RetryCount>
                    <tyl:AllowFaults> true </tyl:AllowFaults>
                </tyl:ApiMessageContext>
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                <tyl:ApiTxnExecutionSyncXml>
                    <tyl:apiMessageData>
                        <Transaction ReferenceNumber=""IKJT1"" Source=""IKJT"" TransactionType=""IKJTEx"" >
                            <Message MessageType=""FindCase"" NodeID=""12"" ReferenceNumber=""R-19293"" UserID=""5235126"" Source=""Vendor"">
                                <Options>
                                    <Nodes>
                                        <All>True</All>
                                    </Nodes>
                                    <CaseCategories>
                                        <All>True</All>
                                    </CaseCategories>
                                    <CaseTypes>
                                        <All>True</All>
                                    </CaseTypes>
                                </Options>
                                <SearchCriteria>
                                    <Case>
                                        <CaseNumber>123456</CaseNumber>
                                    </Case>
                                </SearchCriteria>
                            </Message>
                        </Transaction>
                    </tyl:apiMessageData>
                </tyl:ApiTxnExecutionSyncXml>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
    ");
    
    return envelope;
}
```

The `<Message\>` tag and it's children are the only part of the code that will change from job to job.  I would like to move the Message tag to its own XMLdocument and then merge the Message tag back into the Envelope as a child of the transaction tag.

```
public XmlDocument SOAPReqBody()
{
    XmlDocument body = new XmlDocument();
    body.LoadXml(
        @"<Message MessageType="Config">
            <Options>
                <Nodes>
                    <All>True</All>
                </Nodes>
            </Options>
            <SearchCriteria>
                <Case>
                    <CaseNumber>125487</CaseNumber>
                </Case>
            </SearchCriteria>
        </Message>"
    );

    return body;
}
```

I have been trying to append the message as a child node. When I try to run the "AppendChild" I get an error System.ArgumentException: 'The node to be inserted is from a different document context.'

```
public XmlDocument CallXML()
{
    XmlDocument envelope = SoapRequestEnvelope();
    XmlDocument body = SOAPReqBody();
    XmlNode bodyNode = body.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode envelopeNode = envelope.SelectSingleNode("descendant::Transaction");
    XmlElement root = envelope.DocumentElement;

    Console.WriteLine(envelopeNode);
    envelopeNode.AppendChild(bodyNode);

    return (envelope);
}
```

I have found some information on ownership, but nothing that makes sense to me.

I believe I am almost there, I just need a little nudge to finish. My long-term goals are to move the envelope to an XML flat file that will be stored outside of my code and loaded so it can't be easily changed by over-eager co-workers.

I tried a version of the code above with complete XML.  Then I moved the message tag into its own XML document and wrote the "AppendChild" code at the bottom.  That's when I received the errors.  I have gone through a few iterations trying to configure XMLDocument ownership with little to no success.  I expect to be able to add one or more message tags to my XML envelope and make SOAP API calls.

I also tried modifying the code below, but I was unable to follow exactly what was being done.
[Error: "The node to be inserted is from a different document context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019136/error-the-node-to-be-inserted-is-from-a-different-document-context)

Comment: Your main XML sample is not well-formed. Please fix it first. There are no namespace declarations, and broken attributes at the root, and beyond.

Comment: My apologies, I tried to strip out the chunks of security and what I felt was unnecessary.  I have updated the envelope with a 95% copy of what's in my code.  I had to make sure I redacted the important stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `XmlDocument.ImportNode` to move a node between documents.  eg

```
using System.Xml;

var d1 = new XmlDocument();
d1.LoadXml("<a/>");

var d2 = new XmlDocument();
d2.LoadXml("<b/>");

//d1.DocumentElement.AppendChild(d2.DocumentElement); //fails

d1.DocumentElement.AppendChild(d1.ImportNode(d2.DocumentElement,true)); //succeeds
```

Generally, I prefer the newer linq-enabled [XDocuemnt XML API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xdocument-class-overview) to the XmlDocument API, so you might want to try that instead.